# Category table structure in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that allow user to post their ads.

1. There will be a page where i need fetch all categories.
2. There will be a page where i fetch each category.

What i am confusing: which one is better if there will be lot of (around 20k+)data.

**- Insert the data to each category and main table?.**

*The reason why i need **"post_ads_main"**.
i can use join when want to fetch data, but i don't get the idea to order the 'ProductId' when user post ads.

> ```
> TABLE : post_ads_main
> ProductID     |Category   |AdsDate
> 1             |Tools      |14545454
> 2             |cars       |14454545
>
> TABLE : post_ads_tools
> ProductID     |Category   |AdsDate
> 1             |Tools      |14545454
>
> TABLE : post_ads_cars
> ProductID     |Category   |AdsDate
> 2             |cars       |14454545
> ```

**- one table with index is enough?**

> ```
> TABLE : post_ads_main
> ProductID     |Category(catergory_index)   |AdsDate
> 1             |Tools                       |14545454
> 2             |cars                        |14454545
>
> *where catergory have index.
> ```

better approach is really appreciated.

Comment: please clarify the tags, sql-server or mysql? pick one please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use on table for all of your data. 20K+ is not much for a MySQL Server. If you have suitable indixes, all is fine up to several million rows.

If you split your data into several tables, you will have a very hard time generating reports and other aggregations over more than one category. And you might get redundant data leading to corrupted or incoherent data in the future.